# WPF: Get an event on the scrollbar from Scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I want get an event only if I the user drag the scrollbar left or right.

When I use a MouseClick event, it contains the whole canvas too...

I found that there is an Event Handler "ScrollChanged" but this is not really what I want because the width of my canvas grow every second by 10 and that cause 10 times per second the event ScrollChanged.

I want just get an event by draging the scrollbar with the mouse

```
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="coordinateScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="75,0,0,0" Width="1125" Height="750" Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel" MouseDoubleClick="coordinateScroll_MouseDoubleClick " ScrollChanged="coordinateScroll_ScrollChanged" >
            <Canvas x:Name="coordinateSystem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Cross" UseLayoutRounding="False"  Width="1125" Height="720" Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel" >

            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: What do you mean you just want to get the Scrollbar? The documentation for the ScrollChanged event sounds exactly like what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx

Comment: Can I get it only by clicking by mouse ?

Comment: What are you trying to "get"?

Comment: An event by clicking on the scrollbar

Comment: You're asking for two different things. Do you want the event when the user drags the scrollbar, or when they just click on the scrollbar?

Comment: Sorry,when the user drags the scrollbar

Comment: I showed you how to do that in my answer, and how to access the ScrollViewer from that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From how I'm understanding you, you're trying to access the `ScrollViewer` whenever the user drags the scrollbar left or right. In order to do this, use the `ScrollChanged` event of the `ScrollViewer`. In the event handler, you'll have your `sender` and `e` arguments. To access properties of the `ScrollViewer`, simply cast `sender` as a `ScrollViewer` like this:

```
ScrollViewer currentViewer = (ScrollViewer)sender;
```

That should allow you to access all the information about the `ScrollViewer`.

If you're having a problem with the width of the Canvas firing the ScrollChanged event, then put a check in the event handler to see if the event is coming from a mouse, or from the Canvas width changing.

Comment: But how get I the event ? For example: The user is draging the scrollbar to left and then an event is shows up and in this Event I want get the actual posiotion of my scrollbar

Comment: I just edited my answer, and I think it should solve your problem.