# WPF: Scrollbar movement detection

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer

I'm working with WPF and  I have a ScrollViewer and want detect the horizontal movement of the scrollbar.

I found this but not sure how I can use it in my C# code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventargs.scrollorientation%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I dont want detect a double click or a click on my ScrollViewer because I'm using that for something else.

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="coordinateScroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="75,0,0,0" Width="1125" Height="750" Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel" MouseDoubleClick="coordinateScroll_MouseDoubleClick " ScrollChanged="coordinateScroll_ScrollChanged" >
                    <Canvas x:Name="coordinateSystem" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="Cross" UseLayoutRounding="False"  Width="1125" Height="720" Background="Transparent" MouseWheel="coordinateSystemBackground_MouseWheel" >
                    </Canvas>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You just asked this exact same question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963003/wpf-get-an-event-on-the-scrollbar-from-scrollviewer

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with `coordinateScroll_ScrollChanged` event that is in your XAML?

This handler would have event arguments with `offset` properties.

```
 private void coordinateScroll_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    var status = "ExtentHeight is now " + e.ExtentHeight.ToString();
    status += "\nExtentWidth is now " + e.ExtentWidth.ToString();
    status += "\nExtentHeightChange was " + e.ExtentHeightChange.ToString();
    status += "\nExtentWidthChange was " + e.ExtentWidthChange.ToString();
    status += "\nHorizontalOffset is now " + e.HorizontalOffset.ToString();
    status += "\nVerticalOffset is now " + e.VerticalOffset.ToString();
    status += "\nHorizontalChange was " + e.HorizontalChange.ToString();
    status += "\nVerticalChange was " + e.VerticalChange.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(status);
}
```

Comment: This event is called many times (because I manipulate the width of my canvas) because of that I just want detect the movment of my scrollbar

Comment: Well, you may just suppress notification for the time your layout is being resized.